# Error occuring in sml syntax of real.fromstring

Tags: string, sml, ml-lex

I am new to sml and ml-lex. To convert string to real numbers we use the function real.fromstring. This is my code for conversion where yytext is an array of characters or a string.

```
getOpt ((Real.fromString(yytext)), 0.0);
```

I am using the above syntax in ml-lex for tokenising real numbers.

```
{real} => (REAL(getOpt ((Real.fromString(yytext)), 0.0)));
```

But i get the error,

```
math.lex.sml:5.234-5.240 Error: type constructor Assembly.option given 0 arguments, wants 1
```

Kindly, tell me what is wrong with the fromstring function.

Comment: I don't think the error refers to the code you showed. Search for uses of the parameterised type name `option` in your file, one of it seems to be missing its argument.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Actually, there's no other function or parameter of option type. And when I remove the above code from my file, the program works fine. So, it seems to pinpoint to this particular piece.

Comment: Then it is perhaps part of the code that's generated by MLlex. Have you looked at that? The error message specifically talks about the (mis)application of a type constructor, and there is none in your snippet.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg The type constructor that is misapplied is for the  `Real`.

Comment: @benrudgers, I don't know what you mean. `Real` is not a type constructor, nor is it mentioned in the error message. The problem must lie elsewhere in the (generated?) code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Caveat: I am unfamiliar with `ML-Lex`*

The syntax for `Real.fromString` is incorrect. It is a curried function and the call to `getOpt` should read:

```
 getOpt(Real.fromString yytext, 0.0)
```

Example code:

```
 - getOpt(Real.fromString "1.0", 0.0);
 val it = 1.0 : real
 - getOpt(Real.fromString "a", 0.0);
 val it = 0.0 : real
```

Comment: This reply doesn't make sense. A function of just one argument cannot be curried. Moreover, `f x` and `f(x)` and `(f(x))` are exactly the same thing, just with redundant parentheses. This definitely cannot have been the problem.